# Start service when internet is active in android

Tags: android, android-service

How to start a service when internet is enabled?
I need to start the service when the internet is active state. I have application that communicate with the web application when internet is present,even offline the mobile need a communication,it will known by server at the time of internet comes active.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question. Just create a BroadcastReceiver to listen network state, when internet is okay, start server as usual.

```
public class NetworkBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            ConnectivityManager mgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = mgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
                isNetworkConnected = true;
                //do your work here
            }
        }
    }}
```